# Un-add users imported from a previous team

Tags: slack

We just created a Slack team and one of the other admins accidentally imported all the records from another account while selecting the "add and invite user" option for the old users. This imported a bunch of inactive users. I'm fine with them joining the new account, but I'd prefer that they did it intentionally by following a url I posted elsewhere. Is there any way to "un-add" these users without disabling them (which keeps them from re-adding themselves)?